# Python find all two letter pairs in a word string

Tags: list, python-3.x

Let's say I've got a list of words:

```
word_list = ['WELCOME', 'TO', 'MY', 'B', 'DAY']
```

So...

```
for x in word_list:
    #Do something
```

How do I make it so that the outcome is a list of all of the possible two letter combinations in each word?

1. WELCOME: WE, EL, LC, CO, OM, ME
2. TO: TO
3. MY: MY
4. B:
5. DAY: DA, AY

   ```
   list = ['WE', 'EL', 'LC', 'CO', 'OM', 'ME', 'TO', 'MY', 'DA', 'AY']
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> s='WELCOME'
>>> list(zip(s, s[1:]))
[('W', 'E'), ('E', 'L'), ('L', 'C'), ('C', 'O'), ('O', 'M'), ('M', 'E')]
>>> [''.join(t) for t in zip(s, s[1:])]
['WE', 'EL', 'LC', 'CO', 'OM', 'ME']
>>> word_list = ['WELCOME', 'TO', 'MY', 'B', 'DAY']
>>> for word in word_list:
...    print(word, [''.join(t) for t in zip(word, word[1:])])
... 
WELCOME ['WE', 'EL', 'LC', 'CO', 'OM', 'ME']
TO ['TO']
MY ['MY']
B []
DAY ['DA', 'AY']
```

And to get your desired list:

```
>>> result=[]
>>> for word in word_list:
...    result.extend([''.join(t) for t in zip(word, word[1:])])
... 
>>> result
['WE', 'EL', 'LC', 'CO', 'OM', 'ME', 'TO', 'MY', 'DA', 'AY']
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can slice strings, you can slide each word into all its two-character chuncks (`i:i:2`) in a for-loop, and then check that the slice has a length of two (to get rid of the 1-char string at the end, or if the word has a length of 1):

```
doublet_list = []
for word in word_list:
    for i,j in enumerate(word):
        doublet = word[i:i+2]
        if len(doublet) == 2:
            doublet_list.append(doublet)
print doublet_list
# ['WE', 'EL', 'LC', 'CO', 'OM', 'ME', 'TO', 'MY', 'DA', 'AY']
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want an iterator that return 2 consecutive objects at a time, and step until the 2nd iterator reach the end. You could set up an iterator `iter1` to the beginning of your iterable, clone it to `iter2` and step `iter2` once. Then zip both.

Let's say:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    iter1, iter2 = tee(iterable)
    next(iter2, None)
    return izip(*[iter1, iter2])
```

you'll have:

```
word_list = ['WELCOME', 'TO', 'MY', 'B', 'DAY']
for word in word_list:
    print [''.join(t) for t in pairwise(word)]
```